# What frequency do BLDC motors generate?

Tags: frequency, brushless-dc-motor, generator

When BLDC motor is used as generator, how does the amount of poles effect the frequency of the 3 phase AC that it generates? For example, if I had a motor with 8 poles and I spun it at 50 rpm, what frequency 3 phase AC would it generate?

Comment: "the frequency it outputs": a motor doesn't output frequency. What do you refer to? Do you mean a brushless DC motor used as a generator? That generally doesn't work, because a brushless DC motor is typically a three-or-more phase AC motor with current source electronics to convert the DC to AC; and that doesn't work the other way around.-

Comment: @MarcusMüller https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/322321/can-any-dc-brushless-motor-be-used-as-a-generator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an 8-pole motor there are 4 complete cycles of each phase per rotation, so rotating it at 50 RPM gives you 200 cycles per minute or 200/60 Hz.

BTW, an "8-pole" 3-phase motor has 24 magnetic poles.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 24 magnetic poles.  Could You explain?

Comment: @JohnBirckhead Poles are in pairs, so the stated number is always even. They are per phase so multiply by three. [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/224797/3-phase-induction-motors-with-poles-not-equal-to-3x) answer covers it.

Comment: The link shows only motors whose number of slots are equal to the number of poles times the number of phases.  I am a little concerned that readers might think that this was always true and become confused.